# US Business visa refusal mention in UK visa

Tags: usa, uk, b1-b2-visas, visa-refusals

My US B1 visa was rejected under section 214(b), they gave me one template about 214(b)( with no stamping on passport), which i lost now, its beed 3 years now.
Now my company applying for UK work visa, so i will mention about my rejection, but what i am going to show as proof to them, would it cause any issue?
Please help.

Comment: no, i lost it, it was just a pamphlet about 214(b). no official document kind of.

Comment: Why do you want to tell the UK about a rejected visa to the US?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst because there is question asked in visa form have you ever rejected visa from any other country. Yes and no.
So i was wondering should i answer this or not?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst because the UK visa application asks about visa rejections from other countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some general advice:

1. Your inclination to disclose your earlier rejection is correct.  It's never a good idea to conceal anything; the cost of getting found out is likely to be very high.
2. The 214(b) rejection seems to indicate that the evaluating officer was unconvinced that you were planning to leave the country.  The UK also issues visa rejections for that reason, so they may look more closely at your intention to leave the UK than they otherwise would.  The good news is that people can and do overcome such a rejection with a new application that offers more convincing evidence of intention to leave.  Presumably, the UK would not give more weight to a US rejection than they would to a UK rejection, so, as long as your evidence is solid, the earlier rejection should not disqualify you from receiving a visa.
3. If you no longer have documentary evidence of your earlier visa rejection from the US, that shouldn't work against you.  Just disclose the rejected application, including the reason you were given for the rejection.
4. Most importantly, be careful to document your intention to return to your home country.  Evidence of prior travel outside your country, if any, will work in your favor, since you obviously returned.  Also, evidence of strong ties to your country is helpful.  This could be evidence of a stable job with good pay (which you seem to have), of a spouse and/or children (or, if you have none, of other close relatives) who will remain in your home country during your trip, or of your home, especially if you own it.